# Not able to deploy any war file in Jboss

Tags: jboss

Getting the below error again and again. Not able to resolve it. I checked the configuration files. All looks good. Compared with my teammates and they are using everything same. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:

```
[Server:S-DPCS3] ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of 
service requested in connect descriptor
```

Comment: That means your app depends on a datasource that is incorrecly set. In particular it looks like you successfully communicate with an Oracle listener, but it complains it doesn't know the DB you're asking for; check the SID / SERVICENAME of your connection string, probably in the datasource subsystem in your standalone/domain.xml

Comment: I checked that already. SID is set to orcl in DB, the same is mentioned in the tnsnames.ora file. In domain.xml file also I checked. Connection-url, username, password all are good. Actually when I checked in Jboss management console, the test connection with DB was not successful from there. Getting one error mentioned as jdbc/JobRepository connection is failed in cmd.